# viewpanel rows attribute in XPages set to zero but still display 30 lines

Tags: xpages, viewpanel

I have a viewpanel that I have set to rows="0" with the intention to show all available rows, but when I load the webpage it still display only the default 30 rows

```
<xp:viewPanel id="viewPanel1" var="entry" rows="0">
```

[image]

Why is this happening?, I do recall I have seen this working on other servers, could it be some server or database setting that is overriding the rows atrtributes in the viewpanel?

Server is running 9.0.1 FP4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rows="0"` doesn't work for me neither.

Use a high number instead:

```
<xp:viewPanel id="viewPanel1" var="entry" rows="1000000">
```

(That's OK as you don't want to show more than 1,000,000 entries on client anyway...)